# How can I unit-test a method without instantiating the class?

Tags: python, unit-testing, methods

I have a class `SocketHandler` with a method `calculate_ticket`:

```
class SocketHandler(A, B, C ..):
    ..

    calculate_ticket(self, key):
        ..
        return ticket

    ..
```

Now I want to test the method without having to instantiate the class since it is coupled with so many things. Is this possible?

Comment: @vaultah that's what I'm looking for. There might be a hacky way to bypass this..

Comment: I think you could probably mock the instance - and point the side effect of this method on the mock instance to be the actual method - never tried it but it might work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main hacky way I can think of is making a subclass and overriding `__init__`:

```
class FakeSocketHandlerForTesting(SocketHandler):
    def __init__(self, *args, **args):
        pass
```

You can even set the attributes it ought to have by hand in the unit test.

Still, better to reduce the coupling, of course.

Comment: Nice fast and simple solution! However having merely `self` and `*args` as parameter suffices for my use.

Answer (score 10):

There are several ways using the `mock` library. One simple way is to mock the instance itself, then call the method using the "long" form.

```
class ClassToTest(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def method_to_test(self, y):
        self.x = y
        return 5

fake_instance = mock.Mock()
ClassToTest.__init__(fake_instance)
x = ClassToTest.method_to_test(fake_instance, 3)
assert x == 5
assert fake_instance.x == 3
```

Comment: This is awesome; would love to see some of the other ways

Comment: Worth adding that if ClassToTest.__init__ has code that you don't want to run during the tests, then you can remove the line `ClassToTest.__init__(fake_instance)`, and the method run will still work correctly