# Testing a method without instantiating class

Tags: python, unit-testing

I followed this approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27105491/how-can-i-unit-test-a-method-without-instantiating-the-class), but the issue is that this requires me to duplicate code.

I can override the class in my test, but then I also have to copy and paste the method from my original script to the test script which defeats the purpose of unit testing. Someone could change the original method, but not the one used in the unit test.

`main.py`

```
class ClassToTest(object):
    def __init__(x, y, z, many_dependencies):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
        self.many_dependencies = many_dependencies

    def method_to_test(self, y):
        self.x = y
        return 5
```

`test_main.py`

```
from main import ClassToTest 

class ClassToTest(object):
    # I want to override this only
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    # I don't want to copy and paste this into my test script
    def method_to_test(self, y):
        self.x = y
        return 5

fake_instance = mock.Mock()
ClassToTest.__init__(fake_instance)
x = ClassToTest.method_to_test(fake_instance, 3)
assert x == 5
assert fake_instance.x == 3
```

Is there a way to import the class, override the init method and test the original method without pasting it into the test itself?

Comment: Why can you not just create an intance of `ClassToTest`? (And since you seem to be aware of mocking; if the problem is that you don't have the dependencies available during testing, why don't you mock those?)

Comment: I tried that, but one of them is a database connection that I wasn't able to mock and that's not used by most methods.

Comment: Why not inherit from the class and override the __init__, then just test the subclass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe inherit from the class and override the init?

```
from main import ClassToTest

class ClassToTest2(ClassToTest):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

You won't have the `x` attribute but the method you shared should still work

Comment: @Omega why the initial `_` before method name?

Comment: Typo. Fixed it.